# Preciso de uma mascara que sempre coloque o sinal de negativo na frente do valor digitado

Tags: jquery, mask

Preciso que fique da seguinte forma:
**-20,00**

Comment: Publique os código que você já tentou e as dificuldades enfrentadas e justifique o porque de não ter conseguido fazer a mascara.

Comment: Olá Marcos Ricardo, bem-vindo! Leia esse post para que não fechem ou negativem suas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Interessante também marcar a resposta que lhe serviu  como aceita, veja como e porque nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Obrigado à todos, consegui tirar minha duvida com as duas respostas obtidas e tirei total proveito de uma delas. Sou iniciante no stack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basta concatenar o sinal - (menos) ao valor retornado**

```js
$('input').change(function(){
 var input = "-" + ($('#numInput').val());

 console.log(input);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="numInput">
```

**Para utilizar em cálculos matemáticos requer transformar a virgula em ponto**

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
var input = "-" + $($(this)).val().replace(',','.');

 var result = ((100+parseFloat(input)).toFixed(2));

 console.log(result);

 var resultVirgula = result.replace('.',',');

 console.log(resultVirgula);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="numInput">
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma implementação bem simples para esse problema:

```js
$('#mask').keyup(function(){
  if((this.value.search('-') == -1 && this.value.length > 0 )){
    $(this).val('-' + this.value);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="mask" >Máscara
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Resolveu muito bem.